# How to get the final webpage title in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I basically want to get the final rendered webpage title to perform access statistics. The webpage title we mentioned here is the value of <title> in the head of a page.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Define "get". Where do you want to obtain it? You can turn it around, by always rendering `<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>` which you can then access from code.

Comment: but how if we didn't use this approach, as everyone may randomly set a manual string in the tag, then how can we achieve this? anywhere would be fine, ie. filter, handler,etc.

Comment: You can set the page title ViewData["Title"] = "this is page one title"; Later can get the page title in controller. string a = ViewData["Title"];

Comment: Explain your use case. Yes, you can scan the outgoing HTML in a filter, but you really don't want to.

Comment: I am basically designing and developing a CMS engine supports multiple templates which can be customized by the end users. Yes, scan the rendered HTML is a way ,but not an elegant way, so I am wondering if there would be some other better way.

Comment: if you want to log access statistics, better to log the URLs accessed surely? That tells you uniquely what was viewed. The page title is just a string and potentially subject to change, especially in a CMS. It doesn't seem like a particularly good index for a log.

Comment: are you just trying to get the `document.title`?

Answer (score 0):

i suppose you could use javascript to post the title to your statistics handler

```
$(function(){
   $.post("/Statistics/Log", {title = document.title});
})
```

and include whatever else you want to log

Comment: in theory a user could modify the document title at any time. And it's also open to abuse by repeatedly calling this endpoint to log more visits than actually took place.

Comment: Thanks Jamie, that's a clever solution. But it still has some restrictions, ie. If end users removed the code from the view template, the CMS-as a product may lost the basic functionality.

Comment: @Jonathan this would be in your layout page that contains your view templates, same as your menus, headers and footers.. End user should never see it